# Jsoup HTML parsing and display with multiple views in Android

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm having a problem with displaying HTML data on Android. What I'm doing is parse the html data of a Web Content (it may contain `p`, `img`, `strong` and `a` tags) and display the data in an `LinearLayout`, adding multiple views as whenever I find tags. I'm using Jsoup library that gives us a document containing tags as element. I have to render the HTML on my Android application. The problem is with this kind of HTML Data.

```
<p>STEVE JOBS<br \/>\ \ <img alt=\"\" src=\" http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Steve_Jobs_Headshot_2010-CROP.jpg/330px-Steve_Jobs_Headshot_2010-CROP.jpg" \/><br \/>\ \ Steven Paul "Steve" Jobs (/ˈdʒɒbz/; February 24, 1955 – October 5, 2011)[3][4] was an American entrepreneur,[5] marketer,[6] and inventor,[7] who was the cofounder, chairman, and CEO of Apple Inc. </p>
```

The `<img>` tag is inside the paragraph tag. I'm getting all the elements via For loop from a Jsoup Document. Jsoup provides us with a method `.text()` that gives us the text inside any HTML tag. So When I select the `p` tag and get its data, it only provides me the text including `Steve Jobs` and description. When it's done creating a `TextView` programmatically and set the data. The next iteration in the loop gives the `img` tag, which again I render it correctly by creating an `ImageView` programmatically and load the image.

What I want is to retain the position of the Image, as it should reside below the text `Steve Jobs`. So the order I want to render is `Steve Jobs` text, the image and the description. I don't have any problem if I have to create 3 views programmitically for it. Any help?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me. You can create an ImageView below the Textview containing your "Steve Jobs" text, and add it to your layout. Also, why don't you use a WebView for this sort of thing ?

Comment: @JonasCz Actually, the image tag is inside the paragraph tag. Jsoup doesn't give me the text in parts. It gives the whole paragraph tag as textual data including Steve Jobs and its description (excluding other tags). A simple solution would be replace all <img with </p><img and all image end tag /> with /><p>. So that Jsoup knows it has to provide me with 3 elements in the same order I want.